# Menu with checkboxes to filter Jtable in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, filtering

In my program i have Jtable with items. I want to be able to filter these item based on values (some boolean ad some strings).

**What i have tried/done:**
I have made a [dropdown list with items and a checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDbUE.png) where i can select from the dropdown and the program filters the table. If second sort (no the best name) is selected it will filter further, else it will filter with "fresh data" that i pull from a database and put this into the JTable.

**What the code does**:
What i really want is  a menu/something simular in look, where it is possible to have submenu's containing checkboxes, where i can check of what i want to filter upon. I have made a menu with submenus with JCheckBoxMenuItem's. And i have made ItemListeners, but i have to make a listener for each, and i dont know how to check for which through the menu for which values i have already checked. Therefore i only get either "fresh" list for the Jtable or 1 filter on.

**Question:**
How do i enable multiple filters? and how do i make a common listener that will filter with respect to whatever checkbox i click in my menu and those previously clicked?

```
_sortComboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String value = _sortComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

            List<StakeholderRequirement> listToSort = new ArrayList<StakeholderRequirement>();

            if(_secondSortCheckBox.isSelected() == true) {
                for(int i = 0; i < _stakeholderRequirementTable.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    listToSort.add(_stakeholderRequirementListTableModel.getRequirementAt(i));                  
                }
            } else {
                listToSort = _project.getStakeholderRequirementList();
            }

            List<StakeholderRequirement> filteredList;

            switch (value) {
                case "All":
                    _stakeholderRequirementListTableModel.setStakeholderReqList(_project.getStakeholderRequirementList());
                    break;
                case "Accepted":
                    filteredList = listToSort.stream().filter(StakeholderRequirement -> StakeholderRequirement.isAccepted() == true).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    _stakeholderRequirementListTableModel.setStakeholderReqList(filteredList);
                    break;
                case "Approved":
                    filteredList = listToSort.stream().filter(StakeholderRequirement -> StakeholderRequirement.isApproved() == true).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    _stakeholderRequirementListTableModel.setStakeholderReqList(filteredList);
                    break;
                case "Specified":
                    filteredList = listToSort.stream().filter(StakeholderRequirement -> StakeholderRequirement.isSpecified() == true).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    _stakeholderRequirementListTableModel.setStakeholderReqList(filteredList);
                    break;
                case "Validated":
                    filteredList = listToSort.stream().filter(StakeholderRequirement -> StakeholderRequirement.isValidated() == true).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    _stakeholderRequirementListTableModel.setStakeholderReqList(filteredList);
                    break;
                case "Verified":
                    filteredList = listToSort.stream().filter(StakeholderRequirement -> StakeholderRequirement.isVerified() == true).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    _stakeholderRequirementListTableModel.setStakeholderReqList(filteredList);
                    break;
            }
            _stakeholderRequirementListTableModel.fireTableDataChanged();

        }

    });
```

.

```
JMenu _requirementIndicators = new JMenu("Status Indicators"); 
JCheckBoxMenuItem _RIAccepted = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Accepted");
        _RIAccepted.addItemListener( new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

                List<StakeholderRequirement> listToSort = new ArrayList<StakeholderRequirement>();

                listToSort = _project.getStakeholderRequirementList();

                if(e.getStateChange()== 1) {
                    List<StakeholderRequirement> filteredList;

                    filteredList = listToSort.stream().filter(StakeholderRequirement -> StakeholderRequirement.isAccepted() == true).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    _stakeholderRequirementListTableModel.setStakeholderReqList(filteredList);

                } else {
                    _stakeholderRequirementListTableModel.setStakeholderReqList(listToSort);
                }

                _stakeholderRequirementListTableModel.fireTableDataChanged();


            }

        });
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for filtering basics.

The tutorial contains a working example that does the filtering as the user types text into a text field.

In your case the user will select a value and then you will create the filter using the selected value.

> How do i enable multiple filters?

```
//rf = RowFilter.regexFilter("^" + filterText.getText(), 0); // match from beginning
List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(2);
filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(filterText.getText(), 0));
filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(filterText.getText(), 1));
rf = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
```

The above show how to modify the filter from the tutorial to check the value of two columns in the table. Read the `RowFilter` API. You can use an andFilter or an orFilter depending on your requirements.